# Displaing all task with different hours for current day

Tags: sql, oracle-apex

I have a table with tasks for specified users.

The columns are:

```
TASK_ID
TASK_NAME
TIME_FROM
TIME_TO
USER_id
```

I want to create a report that will show tasks for current day, sorted by start time.

But I dont know how to implement comparing task days with `sysdate` without comparing hours. I want to show on repport tasks for all hours of current day. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that "tasks for current day" means any task with a `time_from` of some time today and that `time_from` and `time_to` are both `date` data types

```
SELECT *
  FROM your_table
 WHERE trunc(task_from) = trunc(sysdate)
 ORDER BY task_from
```

`trunc( <<date>> )` returns `<<date>>` at midnight.  So `trunc(sysdate)` returns today at midnight.  And `trunc(task_from)` will equal `trunc(sysdate)` for any date whose day component is today regardless of the time.

From a performance standpoint, a function-based index on `trunc(task_from)` would likely be beneficial.

Alternately, if `task_from` is indexed, it may be beneficial to this instead

```
SELECT *
  FROM your_table
 WHERE task_from >= trunc(sysdate)
   AND task_from <  trunc(sysdate+1)
 ORDER BY task_from
```

so that Oracle can do an index scan on `task_from`.